# Getting failed to fetch errors while trying install libudev1 libudev-dev libparted0-dev

Tags: apt, package-management, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was tried running this command on Bash on Windows (WSL)

```
sudo apt-get install libudev1 libudev-dev libparted0-dev
```

because a program or a script requires these packages to run properly `f3probe` and `f3fix` by `altMayor`. I have tried to use `apt-get update` and with the fix missing commands and they didn't make a difference.

```
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/udev_229-4ubuntu21_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/libudev1_229-4ubuntu21_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/libudev-dev_229-4ubuntu21_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc-dev-bin_2.23-0ubuntu9_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_4.4.0-104.127_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6-dev_2.23-0ubuntu9_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/util-linux/uuid-dev_2.27.1-6ubuntu3.3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/util-linux/libblkid-dev_2.27.1-6ubuntu3.3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
E: Aborting install.
```

Comment: Have you run `sudo apt update` recently? If not, do it.

Answer (score 3):

A possible cause of 404 errors when trying to download packages via Apt is that the list of available packages on the system is out of date: Apt tries to download old versions of packages, which are no longer available, resulting in a 404. In such cases, the package list must be updated, for example with `sudo apt update`.